# ACF Posts in Theme Options only returning when logged in? Bug?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a sidebar widget I've whipped up that uses ACF's Post Object to get some specific content from my site.

However, I've noticed when I'm not logged in that it returns empty. Why is that? I can't see any controls that would cause that.

There are no logged_in conditionals in this part of the theme.

```
while(have_rows('promo_widget', 'options')): the_row();
    $promos = get_sub_field('posts');
endwhile;
```

$promos is empty when not logged in.

Comment: Can you share the code with which where you 'get some specific content from your site'? I've worked a lot with ACF, - and my best guess is that there are something else at stake here.

Comment: It's a get_sub_field('posts') within have_rows('group', 'options'), pretty basic. The array from get_sub_field is empty when not logged in.